# Queries realted to Dropdown list in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am a new to ASP.NET MVC, I am developing an application. I want to bind the data in the drop down list in create view.

How to bind the data in the drop down? I have go through many question and answers here...

1. I have seen usually everyone suggested to use  `List<SelectListItem>` what is its purpose?
2. Do I need to use ViewModel while binding the data to drop down list?

Can I get simple example where data get bind in the dropdown using viewbag?

I have created a list in controller

```
 List<string> items = new List<string>();
```

and I want to pass this list to view using viewbag and simply want to bind to drop down list.

How to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a ViewModel as it makes interaction with user input so much easier. Here's an example of how you might bind data from your ViewModel to a drop down in your View. First, the ViewModel:

```
public class CrowdViewModel
{
    public string SelectedPerson { get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> People { get; set; }
}
```

So yes, you're right - use a collection of SelectListItems. I'm guessing in your case, the SelectListItem's Value and Text property will be the same. You could turn your List into IEnumerable like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Home()
{
    // get your list of strings somehow
    // ...

    var viewModel = new CrowdViewModel 
    {
        People = items.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x, Value = x })
    }

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Now you need to bind that ViewModel's property to the DropDown on your view. If you're using the Razor ViewEngine, the code will look something like this:

```
@model MyApp.ViewModels.CrowdViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedPerson, Model.People)
}
```

Now when you post that form, MVC will bind the selected value to the ViewModel's SelectedPerson property!

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Home(CrowdViewModel viewModel)
{
    // viewModel.SelectedPerson == whatever the user selected
    // ...
}
```

Easy as that!

---

**Update:**

If you really want to use the ViewBag (don't do it), you can pass your list through from your Controller action like so:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Home() 
{
    ViewBag.People = new List<string> { "Bob", "Harry", "John" };
    return View();
}
```

And then create a SelectList on your View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedPerson", new SelectList(ViewBag.People, Model))
```

Comment: Alternatively, if only one argument is supplied, the DropDownList HTML helper will automatically bind to a SelectList ViewBag property of the same name. Though, as you say, it is usually better to use a ViewModel.